# help formatting news entry in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, formatting

On [My Site](http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/index2.php?op=News) users can login and add news. That works fine. I have problems when trying to display the news. First problem is if the news text doesn't fill all the space by the side of the news image, then the next news item gets displayed too soon (not below the orange breaker) as you can see on the site at the moment. I was thinking to get around this I could set the height of each news post div to the height of the image, although the image is a little shorter than the div so I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Secondly, users put links in their news posts. How do I get them to be displayed as active? on firefox they just come out as text. Could someone point me in the right direction please!

Here's the code:

```
$query="SELECT id, date, title, text, author, media1, media2, deleted FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$counter = 0;
$number1 = 1;
$number2 = 2;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['deleted'] == 0) {
                        if (($counter % 2) == 0) {
echo '<div id="text">';
echo '<a name="'.stripslashes($row['title']).'" id="'.stripslashes($row['title']).'"></a>';
echo '<span class="kisstitle">'.stripslashes($row['title']).'</span><br>';
echo ' (';
echo $row['date'];
echo ')';
echo '<br>'; 
echo '<br>'; 



if((preg_match ("/\bjpg\b/",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bjpeg\b/",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bpng\b/i",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bgif\b/i",$row['media1']))){

echo '<img style="max-width:300px;" src="media/news/'.$row['media1'].'" class="floatRightClear" id="border">';

}

if((preg_match ("/\bjpg\b/",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bjpeg\b/",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bpng\b/i",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bgif\b/i",$row['media2']))){

echo '<img style="max-width:300px;" src="media/news/'.$row['media2'].'" class="floatRightClear" id="border">';

}




if((preg_match ("/\bmp3\b/", $row['media1']))) {

    echo ' <p id="audioplayer_'.$number1.'" class="floatRightClear">Media Content</p>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_'.$number1.'", {soundFile: "http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/media/news/'.$row['media1'].'"});  
        </script>';
        echo '<br>';
}

if((preg_match ("/\bmp3\b/", $row['media2']))) {

    echo ' <p id="audioplayer_'.$number2.'" class="floatRightClear">Media Content</p>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_'.$number2.'", {soundFile: "http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/media/news/'.$row['media2'].'"});  
        </script>';
        echo '<br>';

}

echo stripslashes(nl2br($row['text']));
echo '<br><br>'; 
echo stripslashes($row['author']);
echo '</div>';

echo '<p align="right" id="seperater"><a href="index2.php?op=News#top">Top</a><img src="images/seperater.jpg" width="950" height="6" style="border:none;"  /></p>';
}

else {
echo '<div id="text">';
echo '<a name="'.stripslashes($row['title']).'" id="'.stripslashes($row['title']).'"></a>';
echo '<span class="kisstitle">'.stripslashes($row['title']).'</span><br>';
echo ' (';
echo $row['date'];
echo ')';
echo '<br>'; 
echo '<br>'; 


if((preg_match ("/\bjpg\b/",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bjpeg\b/",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bpng\b/i",$row['media1'])) || (preg_match ("/\bgif\b/i",$row['media1']))){

echo '<img style="max-width:300px;" src="media/news/'.$row['media1'].'" class="floatLeftClear" id="border">';

}

if((preg_match ("/\bjpg\b/",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bjpeg\b/",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bpng\b/i",$row['media2'])) || (preg_match ("/\bgif\b/i",$row['media2']))){

echo '<img style="max-width:300px;" src="media/news/'.$row['media2'].'" class="floatLeftClear" id="border">';

}



if((preg_match ("/\bmp3\b/", $row['media1']))) {

    echo ' <p id="audioplayer_'.$number1.'" class="floatLeftClear">Media Content</p>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_'.$number1.'", {soundFile: "http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/media/news/'.$row['media1'].'"});  
        </script>';
        echo '<br>';

}
if((preg_match ("/\bmp3\b/", $row['media2']))) {

    echo ' <p id="audioplayer_'.$number2.'" class="floatLeftClear">Media Content</p>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_'.$number2.'", {soundFile: "http://kiddiessupportscheme.org/media/news/'.$row['media2'].'"});  
        </script>';
        echo '<br>';

}

echo stripslashes(nl2br($row['text']));
echo '<br><br>'; 
echo stripslashes($row['author']);
echo '</div>';


echo '<p align="right" id="seperater"><a href="index2.php?op=News#top">Top</a><img src="images/seperater.jpg" width="950" height="6" style="border:none;"  /></p>';

}
$number1++;
$number1++;
$number1++;
$number2++;
$number2++;
$number2++;
$counter++;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to your first problem:

> First problem is if the news text doesn't fill all the space by the side of the news image, then the next news item gets displayed too soon (not below the orange breaker) as you can see on the site at the moment. I was thinking to get around this I could set the height of each news post div to the height of the image, although the image is a little shorter than the div so I'm not sure how I'd do that.

You only have to edit your css file:

Change:

```
#seperater {
  float: left;
}
```

To:

```
#seperater {
  clear: both;
}
```

For your second problem, I found this link: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/3713338-post5.html There is exactly the solution you need.

Code from the link I posted above:

```
define( 'LINK_LIMIT', 30 );
define( 'LINK_FORMAT', '<a href="%s" rel="ext">%s</a>' );

function prase_links  ( $m )
{
  $href = $name = html_entity_decode($m[0]);

  if ( strpos( $href, '://' ) === false ) {
    $href = 'http://' . $href;
  }

  if( strlen($name) > LINK_LIMIT ) {
    $k = ( LINK_LIMIT - 3 ) >> 1;
    $name = substr( $name, 0, $k ) . '...' . substr( $name, -$k );
  }

  return sprintf( LINK_FORMAT, htmlentities($href), htmlentities($name) );
}

$s = 'Here is a text - www.ellehauge.net - it has some links with e.g. comma,  www.one.com,
in it. Some links look like this: http://mail.google.com - mostly they end with a
space or carriage return www.unis.no
<br /> - but they may also end with a period: http://ellehauge.net. You may even put
the links in brackets (www.skred-svalbard.no) (http://one.com).
From time to time, links use a secure protocol like https://gmail.com |
This.one.is.a.trick. Sub-domaines: http://test.ellehauge.net |
www.test.ellehauge.net | Files: www.unis.no/photo.jpg |
Vars: www.unis.no?one=1&amp;~two=2 | No.: www.unis2_check.no/doc_under_score.php |
www3.one.com | another tricky one:
http://ellehauge.net/cv_by_id.php?id%5B%5D=105&amp;id%5B%5D=6&amp;id%5B%5D=100';

$reg = '~((?:https?://|www\d*\.)\S+[-\w+&@#/%=\~|])~';
print preg_replace_callback( $reg, 'prase_links', $s );
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah. Great response! Pretty much everything is fixed now except one thing: after the links there's always a <br> that you can see (look on site to see what i mean). I think this has occurred because i set $s to nl2br($row['news']) and after each link in the database entry there is a line break. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution without using nl2br()? Did the Error occure then, too?

Comment: I did try that yeah. But the news posts need to have the nl2br on them as the author may have put paragraphs in their post. I believe it happens because when the script finds the url to hyperlink it it gets to the end of the url and the nl2br puts the <br> imediately after the url, and therefore adding it to the end of the link. there just needs to be an extra space after the url. could that be put in somehow?

Comment: Maybe you can try to do this: define( 'LINK_FORMAT', '<a href="%s" rel="ext">%s</a> ' ); add a whitespace behind </a>

Comment: I did try that. I also tried adding the space after the %s, and i also tried using &nbsp; rather than just a space. Neither of which worked. I'm really stuck for ideas now

Comment: Did you use nl2br() before or after you call the function for finding links?

Comment: thanks for the ideas. I fixed it by moving the nl2br like suggested:


$s = $row['text'];
$reg = '~((?:https?://|www\d*\.)\S+[-\w+&@#/%=\~|])~';
preg_replace_callback( $reg, 'prase_links', $s);
echo nl2br($s);